# r expand.grid to give every combination - not as expected

Tags: r

I'm not even sure how to give this a better, and not obviously *duplicate* type, title but I think this is a different question about expand.grid.

I have a list of variables for which I need a data.frame or list of every possible combination to feed into a bit of ordinal regression.

**The list**:

```
> indVars <- as.list(c("T.P","T.M","T.S","E"))
```

**Desired output**:

```
  > out List of (?)
: "T.P"
: "T.M"
: "T.S"
: "E"
: "T.P" "T.M"
: "T.P" "T.S"
: "T.P" "E"
.
.
.
: "T.P" "T.M" "T.S" "E"
```

**Attempted**:

1. `expand.grid(indVars)` gives a single row

   `> expand.grid(indVars)
      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
   1  T.P  T.M  T.S  E`
2. `expand.grid(indVars,indVars)` gives 16 rows of all two variable combinations but doesn't do 3 or four *AND* where `indVars[i]==indVars[i]` (so you get rows like

   `> expand.grid(indVars,indVars)[1,]
      Var1 Var2
   1  T.P  T.P`
3. Logic says `expand.grid(indVars,indVars,indVars,indVars)` to give all up to combinations (256 of them) but again you end up with rows with multiple instances of the same indVar.  For example:

   `> expand.grid(indVars,indVars,indVars,indVars)[241,]
        Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4
   241  T.P   T.P   E    E`

**Request**: Can someone point out how to expand this list of 4 variables into every combination of 1,2,3 and 4 of them with no duplicates?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to actually _fit_ models of all possible combinations of predictors, then have a look at `MuMIn::dredge`. `dredge` seems to be happy with ordinal regression objects (see ["List of supported models"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf)). See also [different possible combinations of variables for a generalized linear model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664116/different-possible-combinations-of-variables-for-a-generalized-linear-model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this is an XY problem and there is a better aproach to do the ordinal regression.

I suspect that order doesn't matter. Use `combn`:

```
res <- lapply(seq_along(indVars), combn, x = indVars, simplify = FALSE)
unlist(res, FALSE)

# [[1]]
# [1] "T.P"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "T.M"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "T.S"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "E"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "T.P" "T.M"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "T.P" "T.S"
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] "T.P" "E"  
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] "T.M" "T.S"
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] "T.M" "E"  
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] "T.S" "E"  
# 
# [[11]]
# [1] "T.P" "T.M" "T.S"
# 
# [[12]]
# [1] "T.P" "T.M" "E"  
# 
# [[13]]
# [1] "T.P" "T.S" "E"  
# 
# [[14]]
# [1] "T.M" "T.S" "E"  
# 
# [[15]]
# [1] "T.P" "T.M" "T.S" "E"
```